# Extract string from text field in PostgreSQL (using regex?)

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sql-update

I have a lot of rows with `city` and `direction` fields. But from an old import, city and direction are mixed in `direction` field. Like:

```
dir number,  extra data, CITY,  AL 111111
dir number, CITY,  AL 111111
number, dir, number, CITY, dir number, CITY,  AL 111111
```

The important thing is that 'CITY' always comes before a US postal code and I want to extract it and save it in `city` field with an `UPDATE` (using regex?). Is it possible?

Something like:

```
update TABLE set city = SOME_REGEX_MAGIC_FROM_DIRECTION_FIELD
where direccion ~ 'REGEX_MAGIC'
```

---

The working SQL statement:

```
update TABLE
set city = substring(direction FROM '([^,]+),[^,]+$')
where direction like '%,  __ _____';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the part before the last comma, one way (of many) is with a plain [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) call (regexp variant):

```
substring(direction FROM ',([^,]+),[^,]+$') AS city
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8ba2037afe62d9f223da0648754971fe)

Your `UPDATE` statement might look like this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    city = substring(direction FROM ',([^,]+),[^,]+$')
WHERE  direction ~ ', *\D\D \d{5}$'
```

Comment: Thanks!

Excuse my english if I didn't explained well.

Your regex work great. I always forget about negation in regex and it solved a lot of problems :)

I also saw there is another records like "city, XX 99999", with a small change to your  regex it work like a charm.

The working SQL statement:

update TABLE
set city = substring(direction FROM '([^,]+),[^,]+$')
where direction like '%,  __ _____'

102051 registers changed :)

Answer (score 0):

From your data I would gather that you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('direction_field', '([^,]+) \d{5}');
```

Comment: Wolph, thanks, but it didn't work, direction field is more complex and there is postal code repeated and it extract the region code not the city

Answer (score -1):

Get a substring from a regex in Redshift:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
   'hello_uuid_092bab12-8d8b-40ad-b8b7-bc9f05e52c9c_something_else',
   '([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})'
)
```

Result: `092bab12-8d8b-40ad-b8b7-bc9f05e52c9c`